# Backing up a mirrored SQL environment

Tags: sql, high-availability, database-backup, mirror

I have 2 SQL servers in Mirror configuration.

I want to backup these servers but backing up the SQL databases in Mirror state causes an error.

These two mirrors also have a witness set.

I would like to know how do I create full daily backups from the Principal server only meaning that if the current server is set to principal the backup will work, otherwise it won't.

Thank you for your assistance!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the trouble, apparently all I had to do is to check the checkbox near Ignore databases where the state is not online.

This checkbox is inside the Backup Maintenance Plan.

You guys are welcome :)